# TigerVNCでクライアントからサーバーへクリップボードを共有する方法

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, vnc

TigerVNCでクライアントのクリップボードを、サーバーと共有する方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。
サーバー側のターミナル上で

```
vncconfig &
```

のコマンドを入力して、"accept clipboard from viewers"にチェックを入れましたが上手くいきませんでした。
また、サーバーからクライアントへのクリップボードの共有は出来ております。

私の実行環境は下記の通りです。
ビュアー：TigerVNC Viewr 64-bit v1.10.1
クライアント：Windows10 Pro
サーバー：Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

ご回答、何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: デフォルトで双方向ともにONになっているようですが、あらためて指定してみるとか。[vncviewer](https://tigervnc.org/doc/vncviewer.html), 他も含むドキュメントページ [TigerVNC](https://tigervnc.org/)

Comment: @kunif 様　いつもコメントいただきどうもありがとうございます。仰る通りデフォルトで双方向ONにはなっていて、チェックを外してから付け直してみたりも試してみました。それのお陰かはわからないですが、クライアント側からサーバー側へのコピペができるようになりました。たまにまたクリップボードの共有ができなくなりますが、viewerを再起動することで元に戻ったりします(戻らないときもあります)ので、これにてとりあえず解決とさせていただきます。ご教授いただきどうもありがとうございました。